# update query for multiple rows with different where condition?

Tags: sql, sql-update

How to write update query in sql to update multiple rows with different where condition ?For example if i want to change the name of 100 rows of a particular table with different id's?

```
update table set name = 'value1' where id=1,
             set name ='value2' where id=2;
```

But like this i can't write for 100 entries. . Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp table with these 100 entries then update the table by joining this new table, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    Name Varchar(50)
) ;


UPDATE YourTable t1
INNER JOIN Temp t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
SET t1.Name = t2.Name;
```

Comment: But one doubt . . I should create this temp table each and every time when i am changing name field . .

Comment: @SSS, I don't know why do you need to change these values a lot, but you can handle that from, if so, the application that consume this database. This is the only thing I can think of to solve this. But why these changes? and is there any rules for such changes we can think of a solution based in such a roles?

Comment: update table set name (case id when 1 then value when 2 then value end where id in(1,2)). . This can be used but in my case it is not possible as i have 100 entries

Comment: http://redbonzai.com/update-multiple-rows-in-a-single-query/ look at this link once

Comment: @SSS, Yes you can followed the article you linked to create a dynamic php query as I suggested from your application using case statement or the Where technique as described in the link, also the solution I suggested is still applicable too and has  better performance.